# Format integer to have comma-separated thousands

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a list of integers and I want them to display with comma separated thousands. I'm using ASP.NET and VB.NET.  Some examples:

What I'm putting in:

> 0
>
> 10
>
> 200
>
> 3444
>
> 9211129

What I need out:

> 0
>
> 10
>
> 200
>
> 3,444
>
> 9,211,129

I have searched the web and everything, I have tried.  Hasn't quite done what I expected. I hope there is a simple solution to this trivial problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the 'n' formatting: `1000.ToString("n0")` (the 0 means: no decimal places)

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

For en-us / `CultureInfo.Invariant` this will return `1,000`. For other cultures it could look differently (in German it becomes `1.000`), so if you want a specific format, be sure to provide the culture:

```
1000.ToString("n0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Hi Andre, This works but im getting trailing .00 after the numbers so eg 9,211,129.00 instead of 9,211,129

Comment: Thanks Andre, works perfectly, thanks for the link also. Lol I didnt even think of other cultures displaying numbers in different ways! I thought math was pretty much the same worldwide but obviously not!

Comment: Math is the same everywhere. Its textual representation is not. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myNumber As Integer = 1000

Response.Write(myNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Output should be "1,000"